# Replace CRLF and import a csv file in MongoDB with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, csv

I'm trying to import a csv file into MongoDB via nodejs; the problem is (I guess) that I have a Windows CRLF inside each line of the csv

[image]

and, in MongoDB, mongoimport creates a "":"" as last field of each document:

[image]

This causes many problems in continuing the process; I tried this code, but it doesn't solve, and I don't understand why (if I open the csv, I have only a LF):

```
export async function replaceCarriageReturnLineFeed(filePath: string) {
    try {
        const fileRead = await readFilePromise(filePath, {
            encoding: "utf8"
        });
        if (fileRead) {
            const result = fileRead.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").replace(/\"/g, "");
            _log.info(`Characters replaced`);
            await writeFilePromise(filePath, result, "utf8");
        }
        return true;
    } catch (error: any) {
        throw new Error(
            `Unable to replace carriage return line feed in file ${filePath} - ${error.message}`
        );
    }
}
```

And the, the mongoimport is:

```
await importData(
            join(zipDir, data_file_name),
            code,
            "csv",
            collectionName,
            false,
            true
        );
```

[image]

The replace of """ is needed, because otherwise I have numbers as string instead of Double in MongoDB.
The file can be found at the following link:
[https://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/WDI_CSV.zip](https://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/WDI_CSV.zip%3Cbr%3E)

Inside, there is the WDIData.csv

Using $unset is impossible; you cannot delete a "":"" pair.

Comment: Did you try to import the file with `mongoimport`? Should be easier and faster.

Comment: Yes, importData then run mongoimport.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding, I mean https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/ there is no code you have to write. Just use the ready-to-use tool.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: I think the problem is not Windows/Linux style new line characters. By default each line is one record but your data fields contain new-lines. This make import difficult, because new-lines in CSV files are not standardized and handling could be different in each tool and not predicable. The best option would be to find a JSON or XML format of these data. Or try TSV (TAB separated values), perhaps this works better.